I got "The number of ads you can show has been limited for one or more of your AdSense products." Problem
So pretty much I got my adsense approval 4 days ago and I put automatic ads for the first day and it was fine then I added AdUnits (there's like 9 per page) and left auto ads running as well
The 3rd day I got this warning, I searched couple of videos and I followed their method of disabling all ads and removing ads.txt and i'm waiting right now
But I don't understand why it happened in the first place ? another thing maybe to mention is that my website is fairly new, started in 1st of this month after the vercel/netlify free hosting was running out and so most of its traffic comes from the vercel/netlify apps redirecting here so i guess it counts towards referrel which some said google look at suspciously but it seems that less and less ppl are using the old domains to redirect so its going down and organic search is soon to overtake it anyway


My questions are :
Why did it happen ?
Will it comeback now that I disabled ads and how long will that take ?
How can I avoid this in the future ?

Damn, and yet I'm sure that it's all about the huge amount of referral traffic.

I have a few guesses regarding your issue.
First, having 9 ad units on a page is quite a lot. Even though Google has removed the strict limit on the number of ad blocks, in general, it’s recommended to have around 3 to 5 ads per page, especially on newer websites.
Second, the quality of referral traffic could be an issue, but unfortunately, I can’t give you specific advice on that matter.
